# G is a $2d$-regular connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

G is a $2d$-regular connected simple graph for $d\geq 1$ and the number of edges is even, I need to prove there's a spanning $d$-regular subgraph (not necesserily connected obviously).

I wonder what the best approach would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- [Euler cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

**Solution:**

> Take every second edge.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Already on to this fact :) I used the Euler cycle to find a spanning 2-regular subgraph but now I'm in the procees of figuring out how to raise the regularity back up to $d$.

Comment: @Pilatoos Do not mix the Euler and Hamilton cycles. If you have still trouble, I've included a more direct hint.